# Jquery datatables lopping off cocoon hidden input

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables, cocoon-gem

I have an app with a dynamic set of fields.  These fields are being generated with cocoon and styled with jquery datatables.  In order to establish the id of any set of fields, cocoon apparently places a hidden input just outside of the element containing the fields, like so:

```
<tr class="nested-fields stockholder">
    <td class="cell stockholder"></td>
    <td class="cell issue_date"></td>
    <td class="cell shares_issued"></td>
    <td class="cell shares_repurchased"></td>
    <td class="cell shares_canceled"></td>
    <td class="cell shares_outstanding"></td>
    <td class="cell edit"></td>
</tr>
<input id="security_stockholders_attributes_0_id" type="hidden" name="security[stockholders_attributes][0][id]" value="1">
```

**Note that the input is outside the `<tr>`**

In recently upgrading datatables to 1.10.9, I noticed that datatables started lopping off cocoon's hidden (slightly out of place) input element, causing an awful mess with the form functionality for obvious reasons.

**My Question:** Is there either...

1. A way to specify the placement of this input element?  As it stands, I've customized my `link_to_add_association` in the following way:

   ```
   <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Stockholder', security, :stockholders, :"data-association-insertion-node" => "table#captable", :"data-association-insertion-method" => "append", class: "btn btn-default add-button"  %>
   ```

**OR**

2. A way get jquery datatables to tolerate this particular element's placement?

Many thanks for any ideas!

**UPDATE:**  It seems that I'm able to edit the dom after the fact and move the hidden input into a table cell, so it would seem that I might have an ugly solution with a little javascript if all else fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, found the workaround.

The issue actually doesn't have so much to do with cocoon as it does the basic `fields_for` added as a partial by cocoon.  Basically, `fields_for` includes the id by default as a hidden `input`.  BUT there is an option to hide the hidden id input.  All I needed to do was the following:

1. Add the option `include_id: false` in my `simple_fields_for`
2. Add a hidden input in one of the `<td>`s for the id so: `<%= f.input :id, as: :hidden %>`

More info can be be found [here](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/issues/200).